# How to collect all ints from List<Single<List<Int>>> and put it into List<Int> in RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java

My goal is to unwrap a list of singles of list of ints, and get all it's elements, in order to put it on a list.

```
List<Single<List<Int>>> listOfSinglesOfListofInts = getListSingleListType(); // random method that gives us that.
List<Int> intList = new ArrayList<>();
```

My goal is to move move all Int contents from listOfSinglesOfListOfInts to listInt. Here is what I tried:

```
ListOfSinglesOfListOfInt.stream().map(
    singleListOfInts -> singleListOfInts.map(
        listOfInts -> intList.addAll(listOfInts)
    )
);


return listInt;
```

The size of listInt is always 0.

What would be the correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I dont know about RxJava api, but if it was Java stream then you need to use terminal operation like `forEach` instead of `map`. Maybe that is the case with RxJava?

Answer (score 3):

`map` operations do not run until the `Flowable` chain is completed. This `Flowable` is set up, but is not executed. What you probably want to do is run the `Flowable` through a blocking collector after flattening the shape. Try this:

```
return Flowable.fromIterable(listOfSingleOfListofInt)
    .flatMap(singleOfListofInt -> singleOfListofInt.toFlowable())
    .flatMap(listofInt -> Flowable.fromIterable(listofInt))
    .toList()
    .blockingGet();
```

### Details

`Flowable.fromIterable(listOfSingleOfListofInt)`:

- Transform `List<Single<List<Int>>>` into `Flowable<Single<List<Int>>>`

`flatMap(singleOfListofInt -> singleOfListofInt.toFlowable())`:

- Transform `Flowable<Single<List<Int>>>` into `Flowable<List<Int>>`

`flatMap(listofInt -> Flowable.fromIterable(listofInt))`:

- Transform `Flowable<List<Int>>` into `Flowable<Int>`

`toList()`:

- Transform `Flowable<Int>` into `Signle<List<Int>>`

`blockingGet()`

- Transform `Signle<List<Int>>` into `List<Int>`

Comment: I do not have access to flowable for some reason. Any alternatives? Can it be done by zip?!

Comment: `Flowable` and `Single` are part of the same set of API's. eg http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#toFlowable--

Comment: You can run a very similar set of operations by transforming the `Single` into an `Observable` instead of a `Flowable`.

Comment: It seems that flowable is only part of RxJava2, I'm using RxJava. 

if there is no way of doing this in RxJava, what would be the effort required to integrate RxJava2 ?

Answer (score 1):

I did it in Rx-Java.

```
Lets consider below example to create List<Single<List<Integer>>> 

List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(intList, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50);

List<Integer> intList2 = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(intList2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52);

List<Integer> intList3 = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(intList3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53);

Single<List<Integer>> singleList = Single.just(intList);
Single<List<Integer>> singleList2 = Single.just(intList2);
Single<List<Integer>> singleList3 = Single.just(intList3);

List<Single<List<Integer>>> listOfSinglesOfListofInts = new ArrayList<>();

Collections.addAll(listOfSinglesOfListofInts, singleList, singleList2, singleList3);


Observable
    //Iterate through List<Singles>
    .fromIterable(listOfSinglesOfListofInts)
    //Get each single, convert to Observable and iterate to get all the integers
    .flatMap(
        singleListNew -> singleListNew
            .toObservable()
            //Iterate through each integer inside a list and return it
            .flatMapIterable(integers -> integers)
    )
    //Get all the integers from above and convert to one list
    .toList()
    //Result is List<Integer>
    .subscribe(
        result -> System.out.println("**** " + result.toString() + " ****"),
        error -> new Throwable(error)
    );
```

Hope this helps.